# Sometimes, "rude or abusive" is highlighted red - why?

Tags: support, flags, rude-or-abusive

The below image was taken from my flag history.  Notice how one flag is highlighted bright red, but the other two are not.

What does the bright red highlighting indicate?

[image]

In case this is needed, the first question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45509958/debug-reverse-site-js-to-determine-why-scrolling-is-broken-and-fix)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The highlighted "rude or abusive" flag is a so-called *red flag* on a **question or answer**, which comes with automatic penalties, such as −100 rep and IP bans.

The other non-highlighted flags are **comment** flags (without automatic penalties, thus no *red* flag).

Comment: I see, so it depends on *what* was flagged: comment, or question/answer.